# Wide-angle lens 'point and shoot' -- Does it exist?

Tags: point-and-shoot, wide-angle

Not very good with photography terminology so please bear with me.

I've been looking at replacing my aging point and shoot (a Lumix FX500) and one specific characteristic I am looking for at the new camera is a wide angle lens -- not super wide to a point the image is distorted on the edges but wider than a standard lens (since I view most of the photos on the screen and not on print, I want to capture more of the scene).

I get the sense that 'pocketable' and wide-angle don't really go well together and I've read mixed reviews of several options out there on the market so I was wondering what sort of characteristics I should be looking at?

Should I perhaps be looking at something a little bit more advanced than a basic point and shoot?

(The secondary characteristics I am looking at are: size (i.e: pocketable) and GPS)

Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Usually I'm not a fan of camera phones - but - all smartphones I checked come with a fixed wide angle lens (25-35mm equivalent, depending on model) and a GPS, the overwhelming majority of them are pocketable. And any good phone (even 2 years-old models you can get for next to nothing) will have image quality as good as (and probably better than) inexpensive point and shoots.

Comment: However, the lens is fixed focal length, which many people would consider a deal-breaker.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they still seem to exist. On B&H I filtered for P&S cameras that have a 24mm equivalent lens or wider. It looks like there are a bunch that could be considered pocketable, and a few of those have GPS.